# How to print data from a singly linked list

Tags: ruby

I created a singly linked list node with a methods `appendToTail` and `print_list`.

I initialize and link together five nodes like so, and call `print_list`

```
n = Node.new(1)
n.appendToTail(Node.new(2))
n.appendToTail(Node.new(3))
n.appendToTail(Node.new(4))
n.appendToTail(Node.new(5))

n.print_list
```

This is the output

```
n = Node.new(1)             # => 1
n.appendToTail(Node.new(2)) # => #<Node:0x007fa64695bbd8 @next=nil, @data=2>
n.appendToTail(Node.new(3)) # => #<Node:0x007fa64695bb60 @next=nil, @data=3>
n.appendToTail(Node.new(4)) # => #<Node:0x007fa64695bac0 @next=nil, @data=4>
n.appendToTail(Node.new(5)) # => #<Node:0x007fa64695ba70 @next=nil, @data=5>

n.print_list
```

I don't understand why the output doesn't look like this

```
n = Node.new(1)             # => 1
n.appendToTail(Node.new(2)) # => 2
n.appendToTail(Node.new(3)) # => 3
n.appendToTail(Node.new(4)) # => 4
n.appendToTail(Node.new(5)) # => 5

n.print_list
```

Can anyone tell me why please? Here is my `Node` class

```
# Singly linked list node
class Node

  attr_accessor :next, :data

  def initialize(data=nil) 
    @next = nil
    @data = data
  end

  def appendToTail(data)
    last = Node.new(data)
    n = self
    until n.next == nil
      n = n.next
    end
    n.next = last
  end

  # Prints data for each node from this node and each subsequent node
  def print_list
    n = self
    until n == nil
      p n.data
      n = n.next
    end
  end

end
```

Thanks

Comment: You should pass directly the value to the `appendToTail` method, instead of a whole new `Node` object. Right now, you are creating a `Node` whose data is another `Node`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a brand new node when calling `appendToTail`, but you also create a new node inside the method as well. Just change `appendToTail` so that you don't create a new object within:

```
  def appendToTail(data)
    ## last = Node.new(data)  ## Remove this line
    n = self
    until n.next == nil
      n = n.next
    end
    n.next = data   ## change this line like so
  end
```

Comment: Thanks, gotcha, but shouldn't the last line be `n.next = Node.new(data)` since `n.next` is `nil`?

Comment: @the_prole In this method, `data` is the new node you created when calling the function, so no need to set it to a brand new Node. The new node has already been passed as the parameter

Comment: @the_prole yup np :)